# Scons, building C++ executable from only static libraries

Tags: c++, scons

I am attempting to build an executable from three static libraries using `scons`.  However, even though the source files have the `.cc` suffix, `gcc` is selected to link the final executable instead of `g++`.  The following SConstruct demonstrates this issue.

```
lib_a = Library('a.cc')
lib_b = Library('b.cc')
lib_c = Library('c.cc')
Program('prog',[lib_a,lib_b,lib_c])
```

This then output the following commands to be run.

```
g++ -o a.o -c a.cc
g++ -o b.o -c b.cc
g++ -o c.o -c c.cc
ar rc liba.a a.o
ranlib liba.a
ar rc libb.a b.o
ranlib libb.a
ar rc libc.a c.o
ranlib libc.a
gcc -o prog liba.a libb.a libc.a
```

As far as I understand, the `Program` builder cannot determine from suffix alone whether these libraries came from `C` or `C++` source files, and then chooses `C`.  I know that I could work around this by specifying that `C` code should be linked using `g++` instead of `gcc`, but that feels dirty.  Is there some way to tell scons that it should link this program as `C++` code instead of `C`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SCons tries to pick a linker, based on the suffixes of the given source files. Since you're sticking the libraries right into the Program Builder, SCons is not able to see that they stem from C++ files (they have the "*.a" extension now). That's why the "smartlink" functionality of SCons switches to its default, which is "$CC" = "gcc" in your case above.

Against this, you could restructure your build a little, and make it look more like this:

```
lib_a = Library('a.cc')

Program('prog', 'main.cc', LIBS=['a'], LIBPATH=['.'])
```

Now, SCons is able to derive the linker from the file type of "main.cc"...and correctly calls the "g++" executable (if it can be found in the current path).

I'm not advocating this (the above method should be preferred), but another option would be to simply overwrite the linker that gets used with:

```
Program('prog', ..., LINK='g++')
```

Comment: Thank you.  I was trying to avoid needing to rearrange things, but it seems that I can't get away from it.  Oh well.

Comment: You're welcome...and I really believe that following the standard paths of doing things in SCons will pay off for you in the long run.

Answer (score 0):

Following up on [@dirkbaechle's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26064449/8747), realize that `main.cc` doesn't have to have any content. You can leave all of your code (including `main()` in your libraries and just provide a blank `main.cc`.

One convenient way to supply a blank `main.cc` is [`Textfile()`](http://www.scons.org/doc/HTML/scons-user/apb.html):

```
env = Environment(tools=['default', 'textfile'])
lib_a = env.Library('a.cc')
lib_b = env.Library('b.cc')
lib_c = env.Library('c.cc')
main_cc = env.Textfile('main.cc', [])
env.Program('prog',[main_cc, lib_a,lib_b,lib_c])
```

This way, you don't have to add any files to your source code, since `main.cc` will be created when it is needed.